# How can I strike text with custom thickness XSL:FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I strike text with text-decoration="line-through", but I find out the thickness is not suitable.

```
<fo:inline text-decoration="line-through">
...
</fo:inline>
```

I tried to use  but I can't find a way to overlay the text. Is there any way to adjust the thickness of the strike? Or a way to use fo:leader to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set the padding-bottom to negative 1/2 the font-height coupled with a bottom-border. Like this if say the `font-size` is 24pt.

```
        <fo:block>Testing line-through 
            <fo:inline text-decoration="line-through">
                I have regular line-through
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block space-before="48pt">Testing line-through 
            <fo:inline border-bottom="5px solid black" padding-bottom="-12pt">
                I have custom line-through
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
```

This in RenderX results in:

[image]

Unfortunately nothing tried in FOP will work as it apparently does not respect any margin or padding settings on `fo:inline`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no property in XSL 1.1 for specifying the width of the `text-decoration` line. (FWIW, AH Formatter has an extension property for it: https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.text-line-width.)

Using `fo:leader` could be problematic because you might have trouble getting the width exactly right.

You might be able to do something with an `fo:inline-container` with a top or bottom border and playing tricks with the baseline shifts of the `fo:inline-container` and of the text in an `fo:block` within the `fo:inline-container` such that the `fo:inline-container` is lowered/raised to make the strike-through and the text is raised/lowered to be back on the original baseline.